# PySpark Feature Transformation: QuantileTransformer with uniform distribution of the output

Tags: pyspark, normalization, feature-engineering

Link to the document on scikit-learn:
[link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#quantiletransformer-uniform-output)

What it essentially does is, it normalizes the data such that each data point falls under a bucket between 0 and 1 (percentile rank?) and I assume each of these buckets would have equal number of data points. This image describes what I am trying to do.

[image](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/images/Quantize.png)

I would like to use this Quantile transformation with PySpark. There is a QuantileDiscretizer [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer) in PySpark, but it doen't exactly do what I am looking for. It also returns less number of buckets than given in the input parameters. The below line of code returns only 81 distinct buckets on a data set with millions of rows, and min(col_1) as 0 and max(col_1) as 20000.

`discretizer_1 = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=100, inputCol="col_1", outputCol="result")`

So is there a way I can uniformly normalize my data, either using  `QuantileDiscretizer` or otherwise using PySpark?